# Unable login after editing etc/environment

Tags: raspbian, login

After install DotNet Core, I set environment variables in the file etc/environment

`export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet`

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet`

looking have system wide access to these tools I follow [this answear](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37771/setting-system-wide-path-not-working-in-etc-environment).

But it is a disaster: after logout and reboot I am unable to pass a unexpected GUI "Login" window, where if I set my User and password I am refused and can't have access to the Desktop GUI. If I made SSH login using the same user and password I have a successful login.

I try many of the hints in other questions to return the autologin feature to the Desktop GUI (remove .xAuthority, set permissions, etc.). No joy.

Using my SSH session, I proceed to delete my lines in the etc/environment and the system can boot with auto login sucessfully.

What went wrong here? Why I can not set those lines in the environment file without having a system unable to login to the Graphical Desktop?

Comment: You claimed to follow an Answer, then modified a file it recommended against, but did it incorrectly. Specifically HOME  & PATH are undefined, and export is not an environment variable.

Comment: I follow the original question, but the accepted answear recomends add your own .sh file to the directory /etc/profile.d. And those files seems only to be processed after a user makes login.